# Loading multiple files with Twig to access their variables

Tags: symfony, twig

In Symfony 2, I want to load 2 arbitrary files from the Base.html.twig

- Base.html.twig
- A.html.twig
- B.html.twig

All the UI is written in Base and I must get some variables out of A and B.
With Twig, how can I load the two files so I can access their variables in Base.html.twig.
It would also be interesting to know how to {% set %} a variable as a property bag (A and B would add stuff to it)

The ->render call loaded Base.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you'll have to pass it through from the controller.

Otherwise if i misread this, if the A and B files need variables you don't already have, you're best bet would be to embed a controller.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the best solution to me. I simplified it here to make it easy to understand. I am using bundle inheritance; the base lift up a lot of important operations as well. I would need to get those variables from my child bundle. If I can do that easily, then it is good too, however we can only override a controller file I believe (without actually extending the php class).